# Does Google spanner supports merge statements

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Does google cloud Spanner supports Merge statements like Oracle?

For example I have SQL' like below. Will it work ? I am getting INVALID ARGUMENT while running the snippet.

merge P1 c
using (select sumery.RunId from PS sumery where sumery.RunId=1010192) s
on (c.LastRunId=s.RunId)
when MATCHED THEN
udpate c.ProcessTypeCd ='Update'
WHEN  NOT  MATCHED THEN
INSERT INTO P1
(ProcessName, ActiveF, InProgressF)
VALUES('12', 'Y', 'N');

Answer (score 1):

No, Cloud Spanner only supports `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` [DML statements](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dml-syntax). It does however support `InsertOrUpdate` [mutations](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rpc/google.spanner.v1#google.spanner.v1.Mutation.FIELDS.google.spanner.v1.Mutation.Write.google.spanner.v1.Mutation.insert_or_update) which has the same semantics as a `MERGE` statement.

Your question does not include any information how and/or with which programming language you are connecting to Cloud Spanner, but all the client libraries and the JDBC driver for Cloud Spanner support writing mutations. A sample for writing with mutations can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/samples/spanner-insert-data

Comment: The language is SQL. I'd also like to have "upsert" semantic. Having INSERT and UPDATE already implemented it should be an easy task to get MERGE up and running in Spanner.